# Is there a way to generate Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-fifth-generation, pokemon-series

Is there any way to quickly attain Pokemon with custom levels, custom abilities, and custom EVs?

I've got a set of pokemon, the perfect team I use for Wi-Fi gameplay and such, but strong as they may be, their natures are off.  Normally this doesn't present much of an issue, but when I come up against other experienced players, it gets really challenging to do anything to them.

The problem is they all have the wrong natures, bad moves, etc.  The cost and time it would take for me to get the right nature, followed by getting it up to level 100, with the correct EVs, would take years, and I'm looking for quick shortcut that can help me out.

Comment: I believe that you are asking for cheats, and this is not a appropriate approach to GSE. Take a look at our [FAQ](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: About your question, **No** There is no normal way of changing a nature of a Pokémon besides breeding (or capturing) one with the right nature. besides, even with the same nature/EV points, a Pokémon may be different from another thanks to the [IV points](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/IV).

Comment: I edited your question so it'll be more answerable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A way that I have found to somewhat quickly get certain natures would be by breeding. This is the quickest way, short of using an Action Replay, which I assume you don't use. To get certain EV's for a Pokemon, you must fight certian types of Pokemon. For example, fighting a Lillipup will give you one point in the Attack stat for EV's. Here is a great example I found on a website:

http://pokemon.marriland.com/black_white/how_to_ev_train

To answer you other questions, a Pokemon can usually have up to two different abilities, possibly three because of Dream World abilities. For example, a Zebstrika can have either Lightningrod or Motor Drive when caught or breede regularly. However, if you can obtain a Blitzle or Zebstrika from the Dream World, it can have the ability Sap Sipper instead. This is the only legitimate way to obtain different abilities without the use of an Action Replay.

As for custom levels, you will have to train your Pokemon until it reaches the desired level, or hunt for as many Rare Candies as you can. A good way to do this is to get a couple Lillipup that is level 41 or higher that have the ability "[Pickup](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Pickup_%28ability%29)." They will have a 10% chance of picking up a Rare Candy.

I hope this info answers your question.